# Run-time Error 1004 while adding table rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the following code to add rows to a table. I need the number of rows to be dynamic because I am adding rows from one table to my main table, and the number of rows in the supplementary table can vary.

Currently, cell F2 counts the number of rows in the supplementary table, and this is supposed to be how many rows the macro adds to my main table. However, when referencing the *RowNumber* variable, I receive the error message "Insert method of range class failed".

I tried replacing the variable with different numbers, and then the code runs fine. However, whenever I use the variable, I get the error message.

Appreciate any help.

```
Sub AddRows()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim RowNumber As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    With ws
        Set RowNumber = .Range("F2")
        Range("A8").End(xlDown).Select
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Resize(RowNumber.Value).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With

Range("tblDetail").Select
Range("A10").Activate
Selection.FillDown


End Sub
```

EDIT: I think I am receiving the error because I have a table which starts three rows below my main table (this is an import file for online accounting software, which requires a certain number of tables). I played around with the value in F2: anything greater than "4" in F2 results in the 1004 error (assuming the active cell when the macro is run is in the last row of my main table). Anything less than 4, and the code runs fine.

Is there maybe a way to use variables with the `listrows.add` function, since my main table is a list object?

Comment: Are you certain that the `ActiveSheet` at the time this code runs is the one you think it is? Right before that line that throws the error, add `Debug.Print ws.name, RowNumber.Value` run it again and see what shows up in your VBE's Immediate output window: View>>"Immediate Window" (if it's not already shown).

Comment: Yes, I ran the code again with the added debug instructions, and the immediate window showed the correct values ("Sheet1" for name, and "199" for value).

Comment: And, just to confirm, if you change nothing else about your code, but replace that `RowNumber.Value` with `199` it works?

Comment: I tried replacing the `RowNumber.Value` with `199` today, but I still received the 1004 error when running the code. So I created a new macro with just the

Comment: I think the end of your comment was cut off. That's interesting news though. Assuming it's still an issue, what happens you manually try to insert 199 rows on that sheet starting at that row?

Comment: @JNevill, see my edit to the OP as to what I think the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

`ActiveCell.EntireRow.Resize(CInt(RowNumber.Value)).Insert Shift:=xlDown`

I was able to reproduce your error in my own spreadsheet. Range("F2").Value was returning a string value when F2 contained the formula `=ROWS(Table1)`. The conversion fixed it for me.

**Revised Answer**

The following code will append the number of rows specified in F2 to the table in which A8 resides:

```
Dim insertIndex As Integer
Dim insertPosition As Integer

With Range("A8")
    insertPosition = .Row - .ListObject.Range.Row
    With .ListObject.ListRows
        For insertIndex = 1 To CInt(Range("F2").Value)
            .Add
        Next
    End With
End With
```

That works even if there is a table immediately below the table in which A8 resides.

Comment: Initially F2 was containing a Counta function which did the same thing as `=ROWS(Table1)`, but I changed it to the `=ROWS(Table1)` function. I then made your suggested change to the macro code, but still received the same 1004 error. See my edit to the OP, for what I think the problem is.

Comment: What is the significance of A8? Are you trying to always insert at row 8? Or, are you always trying to insert at the end of the table? Because I think I have an answer for you, but I need to know what you hope to accomplish by this line: `Range("A8").End(xlDown).Select`

Comment: See the **revised** section of my answer. I think that might be what you are trying to do.